# What is the difference between calling open_sftp() locally and via a separate function?

Tags: python, paramiko

In the following code, the first test passes, and the second one does not, which I find puzzling.

```
import paramiko

def test1():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('10.0.0.107', username='test', password='test')
    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    sftp.stat('/tmp')
    sftp.close()

def get_sftp():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('10.0.0.107', username='test', password='test')
    return client.open_sftp()

def test2():
    sftp = get_sftp()
    sftp.stat('/tmp')
    sftp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test1()
    print 'test1 done'
    test2()
    print 'test2 done'
```

Here's what I get:

```
$ ./script.py
test1 done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./play.py", line 25, in <module>
    test2()
  File "./play.py", line 20, in test2
    sftp.stat('/tmp')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 337, in stat
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 627, in _request
    num = self._async_request(type(None), t, *arg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 649, in _async_request
    self._send_packet(t, str(msg))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/sftp.py", line 172, in _send_packet
    self._write_all(out)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/sftp.py", line 138, in _write_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError
```

This happens both on Ubuntu (Python **2.6** and paramiko **1.7.6**) and Debian (Python **2.7** and paramiko **1.7.7**).

If I run `test2` first, I only get the stack trace, meaning `test2` indeed fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've verified it on debian/python2.6/paramiko1.7.6.

The reason is that the `client` object goes out of scope in `get_sftp` (and closes the "channel").  If you cange it so you return the client:

```
import paramiko

def get_sftp():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('localhost', username='root', password='B4nan-purr(en)')
    return client

def test2():
    client = get_sftp()
    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    sftp.stat('/tmp')
    sftp.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test2()
```

then everything will work (the function name should probably be changed..).

Comment: That seems like an actual root password, watch out :)

Comment: It was once, but gone long before this post :-)

Comment: If when the `SSHClient` goes out of scope, the channel is closed, does that mean that it's impossible to create a `get_sftp()` function that just takes an ip, user, and password and returns an open SFTP connection without also returning the `SSHClient` object?

Comment: @ewok you're commenting on a post from 2012... you should probably ask a new question (but the connection is the client is the connection)

Comment: [I did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172488/paramiko-method-to-open-and-return-an-sftp-conneciton)