# paramiko: method to open and return an sftp conneciton

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I want to write a method that takes an IP, username, and password, and returns an open SFTP connection to that server.  Here's the code I have, using `paramiko`:

```
def open_sftp_connection(ip, user, passwd):
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, 22, user, passwd)
    assert ssh.get_transport().is_active(), 'Failed to connect to server'

    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    return sftp
```

If I execute this code directly in a python shell, it works fine:

```
>>> ssh = SSHClient()
>>> ssh.load_system_host_keys()
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect(ip, 22, user, passwd)
>>> assert ssh.get_transport().is_active(), 'Failed to connect to server'
>>> sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
>>> print sftp.get_channel().get_transport().is_active()
True
```

But when I put it in a function and call the function, the sftp connection comes back disconnected:

```
>>> def open_sftp_connection(ip, user, passwd):
...     ssh = SSHClient()
...     ssh.load_system_host_keys()
...     ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
...     ssh.connect(ip, 22, user, passwd)
...     assert ssh.get_transport().is_active(), 'Failed to connect to server'
...     sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
...     return sftp
...
>>> sftp = open_sftp_connection(ip, user, passwd)
>>> print sftp.get_channel().get_transport().is_active()
False
```

The only thing I can think of is the ssh connection is stored locally in `ssh`, then when the function returns, `ssh` is garbage collected, and the connection is terminated, so while the `SFTPClient` still exists, the underlying connection is now dead.

If that's the case, how can I resolve it?  If not, what is actually happening?

**EDIT**: I modified the function to return `sftp, ssh` and now the connection stays open.  So it is the garbage collector that's the culprit.  Can this be resolved without returning two values?

Comment: If you suspect GC is the culprit, try returning `ssh, sftp` and see if that keeps it alive.

Answer (score 2):

You need access to both the ssh and sftp instances.

```
def open_sftp_connection(ip, user, passwd):
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, 22, user, passwd)
    assert ssh.get_transport().is_active(), 'Failed to connect to server'
    return ssh, ssh.open_sftp()

ssh, sftp = open_sftp_connection(ip, user, passwd)
print sftp.get_channel().get_transport().is_active()
```

Comment: can this be accomplished without actually returning two values?

Comment: yes but you would have to open the sftp connection outside of the function... 
ssh = open_sftp_connection(ip, user, passwd)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

Comment: so the requirement of a single function that takes an ip, user, and password and returns only an open sftp connection is impossible?

Comment: from what I can tell, yes.