# Keeping connection open in class instance paramiko - Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to open a connection and add a file to the server. I have inserted the code. It is saying that the socket is closed however I am not sure how to fix this

```
import paramiko

class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect('xxx.ie', username='xxx', password='xxx')
        self.sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

    def sendFile(self, filename):
        filepath = '/Users/paulledwith/PycharmProjects/FYP/'+filename
        localpath = '/home/paul/Testing/'+filename
        self.sftp.put(filepath, localpath)
remote = Server()

remote.sendFile('Server.py')
```

RESOLVED: [What is the difference between calling open_sftp() locally and via a separate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925895/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-open-sftp-locally-and-via-a-separate-fu)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925895/what-is-the-difference-between-calling-open-sftp-locally-and-via-a-separate-fu